# SESSION variables doesn't work on mobile when it's not at local network

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, safari

I set up a little social network with session variables and I have done a port redirection with my router in my house, but it seams that it has a problem when I try to make `SESSION` variables, only when I am on my Ipad (whether chrome or safari) and when I'm on the WAN.

What should I do to enable `SESSION` in mobile?

PS: It works on my computer all the time.

[image: WAN Page 1]

[image: WAN Page 2]

[image: LOCAL Page 1]

[image: LOCAL Page 2]

```
Page 1
<?php 
  //Page 1
  session_start();
  echo var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
2
```

---

```
Page 2
<?php 
  //Page2
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['id']=0;
  echo var_dump($_SESSION);

?>
1
```

Comment: Session is a server side concept. I can only think the browser cannot maintain a link to the session somehow. Have you disallowed cookies on that device or something??

Comment: it seams that on my iphone it works but on my ipad we have the same problem... even in google chrome . I didn't see a parameters to disable cookies on safari that can affect google... Now I'm doing an update of IOS, maybe this is the problem... I'll see.

Answer (score -1):

When in mobile you can user Javascript session instead

```
sessionStorage.setItem('session_variable',session_value);
```